# Error ClassNotFoundException when downloaded from Google Play store on some devices

Tags: android

I have got a problem involving ClassNotFoundException. When i "Run as
android application" from eclipse it works fine, but when i download
it from Google Play (same source code but "Exported as signed app") it
crashes with the following stacktrace:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.xxxx.xxxxxx./com.xxxx.xxxxxx..SplashActivity}:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.xxxx.xxxxxx..SplashActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip
>   file
>   "/mnt/asec/com.xxxx.xxxxxx.-1/pkg.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib,
>   /system/lib]] at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2277)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:165) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600) at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.xxxx.xxxxxx..SplashActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip
>   file
>   "/mnt/asec/com.xxxx.xxxxxx.-1/pkg.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib,
>   /system/lib]] at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461) at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1123) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2268)
>   ... 11 more

Answer (score 1):

Try Cleaning the project and export it once more to google play.